# Arrange lua/lualatex data in a Latex/tex tabular

Tags: lua, latex, tex, tabular

I have data in lua, accessible to a LaTeX/TeX document (it is an array).
I try to show this data in a LaTeX tabular form.
I tried several ways to do this but all failed :( . Here is an example :

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline 
A&B&C\\ \hline
2010 & 2,78 &\\ \hline
\luaexec{for i=1,nA do;
tex.print(i.."& "..data_a[1][i].." &"..data_a[2][i]..[[\\ \hline]]);
end;}
\end{tabular}
```

I have this error : "use of @@array don't match its definition".
Basically, everything would work except when I try to put a newline \ in the loop.

Any idea welcome !!

Comment: It seems to me that you have to escape the `\ ` characters: `\ ` becomes `\string\\ `. (So that `\\ ` becomes `\string\\ \string\\ `; no space between tokens) For less tedious ways to do this have a more in depth look at the Lua(La)Tex manual.

Comment: In fact the [[...]] sequence does this job of escaping. I tried quite a lot of configurations : luadirect, luaexec, luacode, luacode*. I tried lua-escaping with the \ "one by one" such as "\\\\ \\hline" instead of [[\\ \hline]]. But to be sure I tried again ... and now it works !!
'\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline 
A&B&C\\ \hline
2010 & 2,78 &\\ \hline
\luaexec{for i=1,nA do;
tex.print(i.."& "..data_a[1][i].." &"..data_a[2][i].."\\\\ \\hline");
end;}
\end{tabular}'
I don't understand well why but it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working !

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline  A&B&C&D\\ \hline
\luaexec{for i=1,nA do; tex.print(i.."& "..data_a[1][i].." &"..data_a[2][i].."&\\\\ \\hline") end}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into issues with representing `\` in a string included inside `luaexec`, you may consider a different representation that produces the same result. For example, `\` is equivalent to `"\92\32"` or `string.char(92, 32)`.